# Triggers : After insert will have to change the data in rest of the records . But i am getting below error

Tags: trigger

```
 public class example{
 public static void method(list<Job_application__c> newlist){
 for( Job_application__c temp  : newlist ){
if(temp.Age__c >=40){
 temp.Salary_Expected__c = temp.Salary_Expected__c - 500;}}}}



trigger trig1 on Job_application__c (after insert) { 
 example.method(trigger.new);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation on Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm):

"You can use an object to change its own field values using trigger.new, but only in before triggers. In all after triggers, trigger.new is not saved, so a runtime exception is thrown."

That being said my suggestion would be for you to change the Trigger context in order to run before update. You could also update the object using a DML operation but according to your code you may end up with a recursive issue.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

A field value of object can be changed using trigger.new but only in case of before triggers. But in case of after triggers changing the values of the records in trigger.new
throws that exception

```
trigger trig1 on Job_application__c (before insert) { 
       if(trigger.isInsert&&trigger.isbefore){
       example.method(trigger.new);
   }}
```

Apex class:

```
  public class example{
  public static void method(list<Job_application__c> newlist){
    for( Job_application__c temp  : newlist ){
 if(temp.Age__c >=40){
  temp.Salary_Expected__c = temp.Salary_Expected__c - 500;}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions . I have small doubt how can we use After insert . if trigger.new throw exception then what should we use for after update

Comment: you  can use before update instead of after update. in after insert/after update you are trying to change the trigger.new value you will end up with error.

Comment: @bhargavgodaba you can add the records to process to a new list and perform the DML operation.